# LDAP SSO with access to SVN, CVS and GitStore?

Tags: git, svn, ldap, single-sign-on, cvs

I have set up OpenLDAP Server on Centos and clients are of various flavors like ubuntu, fedora, mac os x, windows 7, windows 8 and centos as well. I am in a position where all above mentioned OS Clients are able to login to LDAP Server, but my question is how can perform single sign on to SVN, CVS, and GIT ? All repositories are in working position.

I don't want to use apache in svn. I want to use only svn+ssh.

My Requirement is whenever LDAP client logs in to system he should be able to access all repositories without a password.

For Eg. A client logs into ubuntu os and opens eclipse , now he should be able to checkout and checkin without the password because he has logged in as a LDAP User.